# Why are my styles being applied to the admin area?

Tags: admin, css, wp-enqueue-style

All my enqueued styles are applied to the back-end as well. I have never encountered this behavior before.

Here's my code:

```
wp_register_style( 'main-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css', false, '1.0.0', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('main-styles');
```

Comment: what action do you add these on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why are my styles being applied to the admin area?

Assuming that is all of the code, it is because you are enqueueing the styles globally. You need to hook that to `wp_enqueue_scripts`, which will only load on the front end.

```
wp_register_style( 'main-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css', false, '1.0.0', 'all');

function enqueue_script_front_wpse_84975() {
  wp_enqueue_style('main-styles');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_script_front_wpse_84975');
```

You can register globally or put that `wp_register_scripts` part inside the `enqueue_script_front_wpse_84975` function, but you need to hook `wp_enqueue_style`, at least, to `wp_enqueue_scripts` or you will enqueue the stylesheet everywhere. I realize it seems weird to enqueue a stylesheet on a hook ending in "script" but [that is correct per the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).

`wp_enqueue_style` can be, and is, used to enqueue anywhere, front or back end, as you can see on the Codex page for [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)

Answer (score 3):

Where are you hooking these?

If you look at the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), you should add these to a function and hook the function to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) for front end display.

Example:

```
function add_my_css(){
wp_register_style( 'main-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.css', false, '1.0.0', 'all');

wp_enqueue_style('main-styles');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_css');
```